# How do I know if certain extensions methods 'mutate' the object or not?

Tags: c#, .net, object, extension-methods

Feel free to edit 'mutate' from the title if it's a poor choice of wording.

My question is, relatively, simple.

Take the following example:

```
myCollection.OrderBy(o => o);
```

How do I know whether `OrderBy` will/will not order `myCollection` or whether an assignment (following) is necessary:

```
myCollection = myCollection.OrderBy(o => o);
```

Is it a case of having to build it and check every time I encounter an extension I'm unfamiliar with?

**Please note: I'm not asking whether this will or will not affect `myCollection`, I already know the answer to that from using it hundreds of times previous, I'm asking how I'd know.**

Comment: Look at the implementation in Reflector or similar or the reference source if available.

Comment: This question isn't specific to extension methods. And, "If you give a method a reference, …."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the Pure attribute in the class decoration as Steven Liekens said. But in its absence, the only way to know for sure is by:

- **Experimenting:** for example, get an instance of the class and serialize it. Use the method and then serialize it. Compare the results. May not be accurate every time.
- **Reverse engineering the method:** and I hope you have the source code. If you don't, you can use reflection. This will require some judgement if the method is somewhat complex, but this complexity here is subjective.
- **Reading the docs and trusting them -** if the doc is present. This is the sensible thing to do with the .NET Framework types, and an exercize of faith otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

You can't tell from just the signature.

The best you can do is to investigate the actual code, for example by looking at the [.NET Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/). Another thing you could do is check the return type. If it is the same as the one it's being called on, it *probably* doesn't change it, it most likely returns a new instance. Is it a `void`, then it probably does change something inside.

For your specific case for example, `OrderBy`: no. See [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). It 'just' returns a `new OrderedEnumerable`.

Comment: +1. BTW, OP said he already knew the answer for this specific case - I think he wants something he can use on all other cases.

Comment: @Renan: Thanks. It was just as a sample.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to find out if the method or its class is marked as [[Pure]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Pure code does not modify input values.

Comment: "This attribute is not enforced by the current analysis tools; you should use this attribute only if you are sure that the methods are pure."

Comment: Assuming that the original developer did exactly that, you can trust that the method is pure. Otherwise, it's probably best to file a bug report.